# how to store python code output to csv file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

i want to store my python code result in to csv file but here is my python code i am not show my python result in my csv file

```
import csv
import json
from collections import Counter

with open('result.csv', 'w') as output:
    with open('simplejson2.json', 'r') as f:
        str1=f.read()

    output_data=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
    data_csv= csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    data=json.loads(str1)

    c = Counter(k[:] for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith('sta') and v)
    output_data.writerow(d)
    print("there are total", c['status'], "test case")

    c = Counter(k[:] for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith('status') and v.startswith('failed'))
    output_data.writerow(d)

    if c['status'] > 0:
        print("There are", c['status'], "failed cases")
    else:
        print("there are", c['status'], "sucessfully pass")
```

this is my simplejson2.json file

```
[
  {
    "status": "passed",
    "name": "Whiskers",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["celery", "strawberries"],
      "dislikes": ["carrots"]
    }
  },
  {
    "status": "failed",
    "name": "Woof",
    "species" : "dog",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["dog food"],
      "dislikes": ["cat food"]
    }
  },
  {
    "status": "failed",
    "name": "Fluffy",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["canned food"],
      "dislikes": ["dry food"]
    }
  }
]
```

my python code output is :-

there are total 3 test case
there are 2 test case failed

Comment: Save it in a txt file instead? @tokyo

Comment: no i want to save to csv file format

Comment: What is actual issue?

Comment: it appears you're code has an indentation issue

Comment: actual issu is my python code output is not stored in csv file but csv file is generated i want that in csv file my python code result is show

Comment: your code has multiple problems, e.g. `output_data.writerow(d)` => `d` only exists in the for-loop expression passed as argument to the Counter class. also the entire body of your code needs to be inside the inner `with` statement

Comment: also...can you provide sample content for your input file?

Comment: yes i share my input file

Comment: ...what exactly are you trying to count? just status properties? what is the expected content of the output file?

Comment: yes only status var is count

Comment: What exactly should the csv output file contain?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save `d` in csv which is not assigned anywhere. You are assigning `d` here only which will not be available outside here. Or you want to save `c` in csv but mistakenly you wrote `d`.

Edit according to comment:

```
with open('simplejson2.json', 'r') as f:
        str1=f.read()
        data_csv= csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

You can read `f` only inside `with`. If you are trying to read `f` outside `with` then the file is already closed you give you that error.

Comment: my consol is showing this :-data_csv= csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator

Comment: This problem is because you had already closed that file. So, you can't read it again. I had edited answer try to look there.

Comment: @tokyo is your problem solved now? If it is solved then mark answer as accepted!

Comment: The `data_csv= csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')` is weird: `f` is already exhausted at that point, working with `data_csv` would therefore immediately lead to a `StopIteration`. Also, op's program doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: @Timus what should I edit? I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: What I mean: (1) `str1=f.read()` exhausts `f`, there's nothing left in `f`. Therefore `data_csv= csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')` doesn't make sense. Reading from `data_csv` would produce nothing. (2) If you look at op's program: They don't use `data_csv` at all. So this is unrelated to the problem they are encountering. Just saying!

Answer (score 0):

no idea what you are trying to achieve (or why you need a counter instead of just using `len`), but this is a working version of your code:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import Counter

with open('result.csv', 'w') as output:
    with open('simplejson2.json', 'r') as f:
        str1=f.read()

        output_data=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
        data_csv= csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        data=json.loads(str1)

        status_fields = [k[:] for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith('sta') and v]
        c = Counter(status_fields)
        output_data.writerow(status_fields)
        print("there are total", c['status'], "test case")

        status_fields_failed = [k[:] for d in data for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith('status') and v.startswith('failed')]
        c = Counter(status_fields_failed)
        output_data.writerow(status_fields_failed)

        if c['status'] > 0:
            print("There are", c['status'], "failed cases")
        else:
            print("there are", c['status'], "sucessfully pass")
```

content of generated file `result.csv`

```
status,status,status
status,status
```

changes made:

- indentation
- fixed for-loop expression (`d` undefined, iterable required by Counter constructor)

Comment: The `data_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')` seems unnecessary. Also, you could do `data = json.load(f)` directly, without the `str1`-detour?